# Turtle drawing frieze pattern

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am trying to create the attached pattern 4 times with a 125 units of space between each one.

[image]

The code I have written so far is:

```py
from turtle import *
number_of_shapes = 4

#Draw four basic elements
#Draw a basic element

for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
    for section in range (1, 7):
        forward(50)
        penup()
        goto (-125, 0)
        left(36)
        pendown()


    #move to second basic element
    penup()
    right(216)
    forward(125)
    pendown()
```

The result is the second image.

[image]

So basically I am struggling with getting that last spoke on the first pattern and I am struggling with continuing on with the second pattern.

[image]

I would appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You're making the problem harder than necessary.  You need to draw six spokes, yet you're looping seven times. The `goto (-125, 0)` is out of place and not needed.  Your nested loop structure seems reasonable:

```
from turtle import *

number_of_shapes = 4

# Draw four basic elements

for shape in range(number_of_shapes):
    # Draw a basic element
    setheading(180)

    for section in range(5):
        forward(50)
        backward(50)
        right(36)

    forward(50)  # final spoke, no backing up or turning

    # Move to next element
    penup()
    forward(75)  # we've already moved 50 (125 - 75) above
    pendown()

done()
```

[image]